# How to determine appropriate file extension from MIME Type in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, mime-types

I'm using `NSData` object to store different kind of data. Object contains MIME format string as well. But in order to use [`UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:]` method, I need to save the `NSData` object to the file system.

The problem is how to specify the file extension based on the MIME format?

Comment: Maybe [this is interesting for you](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/08/how-to-get-file-extension-for-mime-type.html), its a bit older but handles Mime-type to UTI to File Extension conversion. I'm not sure if it still works tho.

Comment: It still works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Credit goes to @makadev for [this link](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/08/how-to-get-file-extension-for-mime-type.html) which he posted as a comment, but I thought I would add it as an actual answer.  Here's some code derived from that article, which worked on iOS 11.  Note that you'll need to link with / import the MobileCoreServices framework.  The value you fill in for the `mimetype` token below should be an `NSString*`.

```
NSString* uti = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassMIMEType, (__bridge CFStringRef)<#mimetype#>, NULL);
NSString* extension = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)UTTypeCopyPreferredTagWithClass((__bridge CFStringRef)uti, kUTTagClassFilenameExtension);
```